# Connecting clients to a private network

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-domain

I'm currently building a domain network for a small enterprise. This is our current network:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW2Ij.png]

There's also some virtual machines connected to our server via virtualbox bridge. However, now we want to use VPN, and we don't really have a private network to access.

What I think I should do is:

1. Setting up DMZ on our perimetral router point to our Windows
   Server
2. Creating a loopback interface on WS to act as a private
   network
3. Setting up DCHP on that loopback interface
4. Making our clients connect to that internal network

What I don't know:

1. How to connect the clients to the server when they all are connected to the same AP or if this is possible at all
2. If this approach is retarded
3. If we need a private network at all

I've been looking for proper reference on this issue for a while but I can't find anything relevant

Comment: When you say "However, now we want to use VPN" what exactly are you trying to acomplish? Are you wanting specific people on the internet to be able connect in to your internal network? Or are you wanting people who connect using the AP to not be able to connect to your internal network? From your description it sounds like the 2nd option is what you want but that is not a VPN, that is just a segregated network.

Comment: We want to be able to connect to our private network from outside our network. To be specific we want a certain internal program to be accessible from our phones when we are not on our office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarification you are really over complicating things.

All you need to do is install a VPN host software somewhere on the network (it could be the one built in to windows server on your domain controller or it be a different server running windows built in one or a 3rd party software).

Once you have the VPN host installed you just need to set up port forwarding on your premarital router to forward the VPN port to your VPN server. This will make phones that connect in via the VPN act exactly the same as if they connected in via the AP directly, they will be "on the network".

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install and configure the vpn gateway RAS on the windows server itself and start using your existing network.
2. Change the policy/rule in your router to redirect all your vpn traffic to the windows server's vpn agent.
3. You can use the exiting 192.168.0.0/24 network for this to work.
4. vpn will be used mostly for supporting remote workers to work on local network.